# Display Vertices as Circles

Tags: 3d-view, vertices

Is there a way to display circles instead of squares for vertices in object mode?  In preferences, only Vertex Size can be changed.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is a reason for that?

Comment: I want to render millions of imported foam particles and the easiest solution Is to render them in a viewport as vertices (viewport->viewport render animation). Shading and composing of the whole thing can be made in After Effects. There is apparently no other solution to render foam particles in Blender easy way (the only solution is to make millions of instances which kills GPU memory pretty fast) Circular vertices would be at least a minor improvement when rendering the viewport foam.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I lived in a feeling - instancing is light solution (even simple circle Tracked to Camera is heavy?). What about particles Halo?

Answer (score 1):

You can render (*Viewport > Viewport Render Animation*) just as particle's   *Halo* (default particle Point) ... the only one thing that differs is perspective (far particles are smaller than front ones).

Since it isn't geometry, just visual representation, could be memory intensive as representation of vertices.

Under *Overlay Properties* in *3D view* editor enable *Statistics* to see from how many vertices your "foam" consists. Add Particle system with the same amount of particles as vertices. *Frame Start* 0 *End* 1 (or go to *Render > Extra > Unborn*). *Source* > *Vertices* (disable **Random Order**). *Physics Type > None*.

Default size 0.1
[image]

Size 0.01
[image]

Comment: +1... as this could work.. but how to go from his/her data to the particles?

Comment: How gentle request to complete my poor answer :) You are right +1